# I want dynamic dropdown like if user select the type as dog then five dogs dropdown should shown

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

I have two dropdown list first has two elements dogs and cat second has 5 subtype of type like 5 dogs or 5 breed of cat I want to create same functionality using forms.py but it giving me error like clean data isn't found.[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JCXqp.png)
code:

add_pet_form1:

```
class add_pet_form1(forms.ModelForm):
type=forms.ChoiceField()
category=forms.ChoiceField()
class Meta:
    model=Pet
    fields="__all__"
    
    widgets={
        'user':forms.Select(attrs={'class':'hidden-field'}),
        'dob':forms.DateInput(attrs={'type':'date'}),
        'vaccination_date':forms.DateInput(attrs={'type':'date'})
    }
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(add_pet_form1, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.fields['category'].choices = self.get_category_choices()

def get_category_choices(self):
    selected_type = self.cleaned_data.get('type')
    category_choices = []

    if selected_type == 'dog':
        category_choices = [
            ('labrador', 'Labrador'),
            ('poodle', 'Poodle'),
            ('bulldog', 'Bulldog'),
            ('beagle', 'Beagle'),
            ('german_shepherd', 'German Shepherd'),
        ]
    elif selected_type == 'cat':
        category_choices = [
            ('siamese', 'Siamese'),
            ('persian', 'Persian'),
            ('maine_coon', 'Maine Coon'),
            ('ragdoll', 'Ragdoll'),
            ('sphynx', 'Sphynx'),
        ]

    return category_choices
```

add_pet_view:

```
@login_required
def add_pet_view(request):
form=add_pet_form1
if request.method=='POST':
    form=add_pet_form1(request.POST,request.FILES)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
        user=form.cleaned_data['user']
        pet=form.cleaned_data['pet_name']
        return redirect(f'/dashboard/?data={pet} of {user} is added successfully.')
context={
    'form':form
}
return render(request,'admin_hub/add_pet.html',context)
```

add_pet.html

```
{%extends 'base.html'%}
{%load crispy_forms_tags%}
{%block title%}
<title>Add Pet</title>
{%endblock%}
{%block css%}
{%if default_user%}
<style>
    .hidden-field {
        display: none;
    }
    label[for='id_user']{
        display: none;
    }
</style>

{%endif%}
{%endblock%}
{%block content%}
<div class="container">

    <h1>Welcome..Please add Your Pets here</h1>
    <form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{form.as_p}}
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
        <a href={%if default_user %}"{% url 'all_pets' user.pk %}"{%else%}"{% url 'dashboard'    %}"{%endif%}><button type="button" class="btn btn-info">Cancel</button></a>
    </form>
</div>
<br>
{%endblock%}
```

models.py

```
ANIMAL_CHOICES = [
    ('dog', 'dog'),
    ('cat', 'cat'),
]
GENDER=[
('Male','Male'),
('Female','Female')
]
class Pet(models.Model):
    user=models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    pet_name=models.CharField(max_length=200)
    type=models.CharField(max_length=3,choices=ANIMAL_CHOICES,default='dog')
    category=models.CharField(max_length=200)
    dob=models.DateField(null=True)
    weight=models.CharField(max_length=100)
    gender=models.CharField(max_length=200,choices=GENDER,default='Male')
    vaccination_date=models.DateField(null=True,blank=True)
    image=models.ImageField(upload_to='pet_prof_images/')
```

I wanted to add dropdown to the subtype as option 5 breeds of cat or five breeds of dog thats how user will select the type of animal either dog or cat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a general problem. Django is the **back**end of your application. The default interactions of django happen when you reload or load the site. If I understand you correctly you want dropdown2 to display "Dogbreed1" and "Dogbreed2" when "Dog" is selected at dropdown1, whereas you want dropdown2 do display "Catbreed1" and "Catbreed2" when "Cat" is selected at dropdown1.

But do you really want to reload the site after selecting the first dropdown?!

What you are trying to achieve has to be handled by the **front**end of your application and is not django/backend related. This does not require reloading.

One way of doing it would be to simply add both dropdowns, catbreeds **and** dogbreeds, to the html and then change its visibility with CSS depending on the choice of dropdown1 utilizing javascripts `onchange` event handler.

Comment: Yeah, I thought so, but also thought not to use java-script, I am going to create a drop down using forms.py can I override the same dropdown in frontend using css?

Comment: I don't think you can acquire this with CSS only, since it is kind of static. But the javascript task is fairly easy. If dog selected display dropdown1, else display dropdown2. I am sure your form needs to include both dropdowns, and the javascript then decides which one to display. I can't help with javascript code though...

Comment: Yeah, I achieve it using addEventListener of JavaScript.